# Parameter error with a script tag and alert

Tags: node.js, express

I am getting the following error showing up in my logger.

```
URIError: Failed to decode param '/%db<script>alert(539043);</script>/'
at decodeURIComponent (<anonymous>)
at decode_param (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:172:12)
at Layer.match (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:123:27)
at matchLayer (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:574:18)
at next (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:220:15)
at app.use (/usr/src/app/app.js:83:9)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
at /usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
at Function.process_params (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
```

I think this is someone trying to probe my site for some vulnerability. This occurs 2 times every week like clockwork.

Around the same time I get the following error too:

```
URIError: Failed to decode param '/%c0%ae%c0%ae/%c0%ae%c0%ae/%c0%ae%c0%ae/%c0%ae%c0%ae/%c0%ae%c0%ae/%c0%ae%c0%ae/%c0%ae%c0%ae/%c0%ae%c0%ae/%c0%ae%c0%ae/%c0%ae%c0%ae/%c0%ae%c0%ae/%c0%ae%c0%ae/etc/passwd'
    at decodeURIComponent (<anonymous>)
    at decode_param (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:172:12)
    at Layer.match (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:123:27)
    at matchLayer (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:574:18)
    at next (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:220:15)
    at app.use (/usr/src/app/app.js:83:9)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
```

Is there some sort of way to prevent this? Should I be concerned about this? Is there a standard way of dealing with parameters that are not legitimate.